# Error Failed to load resource:

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I may be get some help for my following problem ..

I have defined One-to-One mapping as following

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public StudentReport StudentReport { get; set; }
}

public class StudentReport
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Student")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RollNumber { get; set; }
    public string StudentType { get; set; }

    public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

The existing IQueryable works fine without including StudentReport. Table 2, 3 and 4 have ICollection navigation property in Table1.

```
private IQueryable<StudentReport> buildQueryIncludingCollections()
{

    IQueryable<StudentReport> query = _context.Table1
                .Include(x => x.Table2)
                .Include(x => x.Table3)
                .Include(x => x.Table3)
                 return query;
    }
```

But if i include StudentReport in iQueryable it construct query but in my console i get always error

```
IQueryable<StudentReport> query = _context.Table1
            .Include(x => x.Table2)
            .Include(x => x.Table3)
            .Include(x => x.Table3)
            .Include(x => x.StudentReport)
             return query;
}
```

> Error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of
>   500 (Internal Server Error)XMLHttpRequest cannot load  No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present onthe requested
>   resource. Originis therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP
>   status code 500.

I have no idea where is it going wrong... if someone already have got this issue and know the resolution please share your comments.

**EDIT**

```
// GET 
// api/StudentReports/GetDailyStudentReport/?studentId={studentId}&date={date} 



        [HttpGet] 
        [ActionName("DefaultAction")] 
        public StudentReport GetDailyStudentReport(Guid studentId, DateTim date) 
        { 
          StudentReport studentReport = _svc.StudentReport(studentId, date); 
          if (studentReport != null) 
             return studentReport; 
          else 
             throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound); 
        }
```

Comment: why is there a `CORS` issue? Also make `StudentReport` virtual.

Comment: Same CORS issue with Virtual as well, I am not sure this problem is with Mapping or this problem is with LINQ or Client...

Comment: Any `WebApi` thing related to your project?

Comment: Yes, and code for api controller is         // GET api/StudentReports/GetDailyStudentReport/?studentId={studentId}&date={date}
        [HttpGet]
        [ActionName("DefaultAction")]
        public StudentReport GetDailyStudentReport(Guid studentId, DateTime date)
        {
            StudentReport studentReport = _svc.StudentReport(studentId, date);

            if (studentReport != null)
                return studentReport;
            else
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

Comment: where are you making the api call? can you show some code from there?Also the `Url`s of the two web apps.

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly this is related to cross origin requests in `WebApi`.You need to configure `CORS` by installing a package from `NuGet`.

A very detailed explanation can be found:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api